# Wordpress multisite transfer to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, dns, transfer

everybody. 
Who can help my with my problem.

I'm whould transfer my multisite to subdomain, but after all standard operations, I have problem: my site url like "subdomain.domain.com" redirect me to original site "domain.com"

This the initial part of my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed on
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css,rewrite_css,combine_css,combine_heads
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_dns_prefetch,local_storage_cache,extend_cache
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript,combine_javascript,make_google_analytics_async
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters fallback_rewrite_css_urls
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_google_font_css,flatten_css_imports
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images,recompress_images,responsive_images,resize_images
    </IfModule>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^notefornotebooks\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.notefornotebooks\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/notefornotebooks\.com" [R=301,L]
    SetEnv PHPRC /home/virtalen/public_html/php.ini

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.virtalent.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Comment: can you post what have you tried? you can post your DNS zones in a edit of you post to make it easier to understand what is the problem...

Comment: I have site www.virtalent.com
Now I create subdomain www.amp.virtalent.com

In amp directory on server I put all files of www.virtalent.com. I create new DB and migrate old DB to new DB.  In wp-config I change all credentials to new DB.

Comment: Are you running it on apache? Do you have an htaccess?

Comment: yes, i have htaccess . I used htaccess of original site

Comment: can you add it to your question?

Comment: it's to long to this filed

Comment: post it anyway...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KR-6G3ZlDHMSYULMjO9q6b-rhHJBm5t7tMAeYY6QtJ0/edit?usp=sharing